# Windows 7 auto adjust screen resolution when plugging in new monitor

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I prefer to set my main screen resolution to 1366x768 instead of the recommended 1600x900. However every time when plugging in another monitor, Windows 7 will auto adjust both screen resolution to its recommended value, which set my main monitor to 1600x900. Is there a way to not auto adjust main monitor? Or to change the default auto adjust value to 1366x768. Or maybe have a powershell script/batch script to one click to adjust resolution back to 1366x768. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience has been that once Windows and all graphics drivers are installed correctly, and after the first time you have plugged in the respective external displays etc., Windows 7 (or the drivers) will remember the way you had it previously set up.

I believe however it stores it based on the EDID info of the monitor, which may not always be present or consistent and may often depend on the type of connector used. I have had extremely consistent results using digital connections (DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort), whereas when using analog the computer's ability to "remember" the last settings is sometimes off.

By the way I generally do not use, nor do I recommend drivers for your MONITOR, except for certain high-end models.